# How to make bars independent and unrelated in BarChart of MpChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I want bars independent in barchart of mpchart library..

I have tried applying percentage etc but none is the result I expect.

for (int i = 0;rs.next() ;)
                    {

```
        float totalplanned=(rs.getFloat("PlannedReco")+rs.getFloat("AdvTrgt"))/1000000;
                    float advanceplanned=(rs.getFloat("AdvTrgt"))/1000000;
                    float creditplanned=(rs.getFloat("PlannedReco"))/1000000;//

                    float totalachieved=(rs.getFloat("AdvanceAchi")+rs.getFloat("CreditAchieved"))/1000000;
                    float advanceachi=(rs.getFloat("AdvanceAchi"))/1000000;
                    float creditachieved=(rs.getFloat("CreditAchieved"))/1000000;

                    float totalplannedPer=(totalplanned/totalplanned)*100;
                    float advanceplannedPer=(advanceplanned/totalplanned)*100;
                    float creditplannedPer=(creditplanned/totalplanned)*100;

                    float totalachievedPer=(totalachieved/totalachieved)*100;
                    float advanceachiPer=(advanceachi/totalachieved)*100;
                    float creditachievedPer=(creditachieved/totalachieved)*100;

                    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i++, new float[]{advanceplannedPer,creditplannedPer,totalplannedPer}));
                    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i++, new float[]{advanceachiPer,creditachievedPer,totalachievedPer}));
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qhv6.jpg)

Comment: can you elaborate the bar independence ?

Comment: I want all bars in same size ... the bars should not be drawn relative to each other.Its stack barchart.

Comment: can you add an image of what is your result and what you expect

Comment: I have added image in question.In first graph bars are equal because I used percentage concept but when I use values instead of percentage.The size of bars drawn relative according to values.That's why I want each bar independent.

Answer (score 0):

There is now i have done

```
float floatValue = 0.5f;
```

inside for loop

```
entries.add(new BarEntry(floatValue, Math.abs(valueFloat)));
floatValue = floatValue + 1;
```

So the gaps between entries will be same and also their width

Comment: Its neither about gap nor width.It's all about same height with different values.

Comment: add the library as a module and make your changes as i  think that this library take the height and also print that value there on top of bar.
So you have to make it constant